# Remove by order TitleWindows in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I create 3 TitleWindow:

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp( TitleWindow1, root, false);
PopUpManager.addPopUp( TitleWindow2, root, false);
PopUpManager.addPopUp( TitleWindow3, root, false );
```

And then I manage those position and depth using mouse. Now I want to delete them by depth.
In my TitleWindow add listener:

```
root.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );

private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent = null):void {
     if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE && this. ) { //!!!! how to detect this window depth, that it at first plan??                 

                event.preventDefault();         
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                closeHandler();
            }
        }
   }
```

How does me solve this issue?

Comment: Flex doesn't keep track of a Windows depth; so you'll really have to create your own "Z-Order Manger" style class to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep track of this when you add the pop ups.  Here is an example class that extends the pop up manager:

```
package
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
import mx.core.IFlexModuleFactory;
import mx.core.UIComponent;
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

public class PopManagerDepth extends PopUpManager
{
    public function PopManagerDepth() { super(); }
    public static var popUpsByDepth :ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public static function addPopUpWithDepth(window:IFlexDisplayObject,
                                    parent:DisplayObject,
                                    modal:Boolean = false,
                                    childList:String = null,
                                    moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):void
    {
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(window, parent, modal, childList, moduleFactory);
        PopManagerDepth.popUpsByDepth.addItem( window );
    }
    public static function removeLastPopUp():void{
        PopManagerDepth.removePopUpByIndex(PopManagerDepth.popUpsByDepth.length);
    }
    public static function removePopUpByIndex( idx :uint ):void{
        if( PopManagerDepth.popUpsByDepth.length > idx){
            PopUpManager.removePopUp( popUpsByDepth.getItemAt(  idx ) as IFlexDisplayObject );
        }
    }
}
}
```

You'd use this class to add your popups, just like popupmanager but with this method:

```
PopManagerDepth.addPopUpWithDepth( .... );
```

The difference is there is a new method you'd use to remove them :

```
PopManagerDepth.removeLastPopUp();
```

or

```
PopManagerDepth.removePopUpByIndex();
```

Should do the trick, sorry I cant test it right now, but should work or close to it.  I'll help ya debug if needed   :)

Comment: Hm, intresting solution. But what about this: I change windows depth, and I want to delete them by z-oreder. For example, I create windows 1,2,3 and push them into collection [1,2,3]. And then I move them by z-order by mouse, and I get 3,1,2 order in display container, but in may collection [1,2,3] order. In my case LastPopUp is 2 not 3.

Comment: By the way, you cant override static methods

Comment: Oops- Here, I edited code for you.  Use addPopUpWithDepth() for adding them, you can use removeLastPopUp() or removePopUpByIndex() to get rid of them.  Should address your issue.  ;)

Comment: But how to know z-order of TitleWindows in display container, after move them by mouse? It needs me to sort popUpsByDepth.

Comment: If you want to track z order depth, just put listeners when any of the boxes get focus and change their order in the array collection (slice it from current position and then addItem to put it at end of collection).  Since this is a static class you can access it from any component, for example : PopManagerDepth.popUpsByDepth.getItemIndex(this)

Comment: There is an example below. I use inactive and normal states in TitleWindow. But this states set also PopUpManager, when you close one of the windows. And the question is, how to detect who set normal state by mouse or PopupManager?

Answer (score 1):

Now, I can offer one idea, I use state inactive:

```
private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent = null):void {
        if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE 
                && this.getCurrentSkinState() != "inactive" ) {

            event.preventDefault();         
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            closeHandler();
        }
    }

override protected function stateChanged (oldState:String, newState:String, recursive:Boolean) : void {
        super.stateChanged( oldState, newState, recursive );            
        if ( oldState == "inactive" && newState == "normal" ) {
            PopUpManager.bringToFront( this );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem is to determine whose set normal state : user or PopUpManager

Answer (score 0):

By Windows depth do you mean the z-index ?  If so you might want to try the getChildIndex and removeChildAt methods on the DisplayObject class.  However, since PopUps exists in a different heirarchy than the rest of the general components, I am unsure if this will work but it is a start ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Create an `Array` to keep track of each `TitleWindow` instance you pop up. You can use the Array index as a z-index indicator.
2. In your `closeHandler()` method, iterate through each member of the `Array` and close that `TitleWindow` instance.